# Webpage works in VS 2012, but doesn't work correctly in IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012

I have been tasked with updating some internal webpages from needing users to login every time with the domain account, to be able to use Single Sign.

A person here before me, added some code into one of the sites, but never fully implemented it, so I have picked up the baton to finish this.

I have three sites to update. using DotNetOpenAuth.Core, (As this has already been used for another site that was done).

When I make the changes in VS, this works, using my login, I can run the site in IE and no login box comes up, it takes me straight to the first page.

I am local admin on my machine, so I add a new webpage to IIS, V4.0 Application pool in integrated moce.
Windows Authentication in both the web.config and the page, yet, it always gives me the actual login page rather than bypassing it.

I have spent a few days looking round, and have read many posts about checking the Authentication mode, and other bits, but still nothing seems to stop this from happening.

I have gone back to the start today, and deleted everything I had done, I had taken a back up pre making any changes), and have started on this making the same changes, and one at a time testing them, and, as before while it works fine in VS, not giving me a log in page, when I run it in IIS, it always does.

Does anyone have an experience they have had with a similar issue, and how did they solve it.

The stupid thing about this, is out of the three I have changed, one has worked, yet, I made all the same changes.

I can't fiddle around with the host file, as the server this will be going on ruins a number of sites, all of which are used within the business on a daiy basis, I also can't make base changes to entity framework, again some of the sites have older data in so cannot be changed, which is some of the suggestions I have read.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so very oddly I have managed to solve this in the most basic way possible.

Originally, I was just overwriting the site that existed, but clearly something was wrong, because as soon as I created a new one and added it to the DNS, it work, so something must have been wrong with the first site, even though I made sure that every thing like Forms to Windows Authentication had been set.